# How can I make the numbers in this code right adjusted?

Tags: java

How do I make the numbers in my code right adjusted?
Were should I insert the System.out.printf() and how do I use it?
Also how can I make numbers left adjusted?

```
public class JTROLL
{
    public static void main(String[] Theory)
    {
        int k,i,j;

        System.out.print("The numbers are:"                                                );
        for (k = 0; k < 50; k++)
        {
            for ( i = k; i < 50; i++)
            {
                for ( j = i; j < 50; j++)
                {
                    if ( (k+1)*(k+1) + (i+1)*(i+1) == (j+1)*(j+1)                          )
                    {
                        System.out.println( "\n\t\t  " + (k+1) + ", "
                                                       + (i+1) + ", "
                                                       + (j+1)           );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add an example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: @user714965 I want the numbers I print when I run the program to be right adjusted.

Comment: Forget about it until it's absolutely necessary for you. Java is mostly used for GUI-programming rather than console-oriented applications.

Comment: @Lion It is required for me. It's an assignment. :-P

Comment: Please don't ask the exact same question multiple times: [How can I make the numbers that I print in this code right adjusted?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286083/how-can-i-make-the-numbers-that-i-print-in-this-code-right-adjusted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do the trick as you expect.

```
import java.util.Formatter;

final public class Main
{    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Formatter fmt = new Formatter();
        fmt.format("|%10.2f|", 123.123);
        System.out.println(fmt);

        fmt = new Formatter();
        fmt.format("|%10.2f|", 1.13);
        System.out.println(fmt);

        fmt = new Formatter();
        fmt.format("|%10.2f|", 152123.16777);
        System.out.println(fmt);

        fmt = new Formatter();
        fmt.format("|%10.2f|", 99.777);
        System.out.println(fmt);
    }
}
```

You may somewhat need to modify it to suit your format.

---

It produces the following output on the console.

```
|    123.12|
|      1.13|
| 152123.17|
|     99.78|
```

Comment: Quoting homework tag info: "Homework means the question is requesting help with school homework. This lets potential answerers know that they SHOULD guide the student in solving the problem, and SHOULD NOT simply show the complete answer." Full answers to HW occasionally earn downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Append your numbers and ", " separators to a StringBuilder.
2. Find the length of your StringBuilder.
3. Calculate how far right you need to shift your numbers.
4. Put the appropriate number of spaces into a String.
5. `println(spacerString + myStringBuilder.toString());`

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of examples and explanatyions on formatting on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html. To right adjust the integers use something like this:

```
System.out.println("The numbers are:");
for (k = 0; k < 50; k++) {
    for (i = k; i < 50; i++) {
        for (j = i; j < 50; j++) {
            if ((k + 1) * (k + 1) + (i + 1) * (i + 1) == (j + 1) * (j + 1)) {
                System.out.format("\t\t%3d,%3d,%3d%n", (k + 1), (i + 1), (j + 1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```