# How can I make the numbers that I print in this code right adjusted?

Tags: java

How can I make the numbers that I print in this code right adjusted?
Since the numbers in the code are variables do I need to do something different than normally adjusting it?

```
 a = 4                                                                                                      ;
 b = 4                                                                                                      ;
 c = 1                                                                                                      ;
 x = 2                                                                                                      ;
 Root                      = (-1*b + Math.sqrt( Math.pow(b,2) - 4*a*c)/ 2*a                                );
 CoefficientOfXSquared     = (-(b*x+c)/(Math.pow(x,2))                                                     );
 CoefficientOfX            = (-(a*x+c)-c/x                                                                 );
 Constant                  = (-(a*Math.pow(x,2)+b*x)                                                       );
 System.out.println("\n\n\t    Given that: \n\t    CoefficientOfXSquared = " +a                            );
 System.out.println("\n\t    CoefficientOfX        = " +b                                                  );
 System.out.println("\n\t    Constant              = " +c                                                  );
 System.out.println("\n\t    Root                  = " +x                                                  );
 System.out.println("\n\n\t    x = " + Root                                                                );
 System.out.println("\n\t    a = " +  CoefficientOfXSquared                                                );
 System.out.println("\n\t    b = " +  CoefficientOfX                                                       );
 System.out.println("\n\t    c = " +  Constant                                                             );
 System.out.println("\n\n\n"                                                                               );
```

I would appreciate it if someone could explain how to make it right adjusted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using string format method to print them.  Like this:

```
double x=1234.56;
double y=78.678;
System.out.printf("%n\t Root          =  %12.4f",  x);
System.out.printf("%n\t Constant      =  %12.4f%n",  y);
```

which gives:

```
Root          =     1234.5600
Constant      =       78.6780
```

I am assuming that these are doubles.   Look up printf for more info.
Cliff

Answer (score 1):

I think the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) are about the best for this, shows how to format numerics outputs using `printf()` here is also a great tutorial on [formatting numbers in java](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~vaucher/Java/tutorials/Formatting.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this to right justify the text.

```
String.format("%50s", "Root = " + root);
```

Try String format function, [format arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) provide many options to customize the printing.